# How to properly parse of JSON decimal types in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In an Azure SQL database I have a table which contains a column with a JSON string like this:

```
{"Id":"4b11c702-d4b2-47f4-a8d6-0b8ab9f53c99","Date":"2021-11-15T00:16:43.7300189+00:00","Source":"AtlasEarth","SourceTransactionId":"5ad129d3-2b79-44b1-b617-2d86d352003a","SourceTransactionType":"Rent","Amount":0.000000000000000111}
```

As part of an Azure Data Flow, I'm trying to parse that JSON string and put some of its properties in a complex object. I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7O7AJcuqoY).

The parse works for most of parts. However, the `Amount` column (which came as serialized from a .Net `decimal` property) is coming with the format not correct.

[image: Data preview]

So my question is, how can I get that column with the correct format? I tried both float and double and both gives the same result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> how can I get that column with the correct format? I tried both float and double and both gives the same result.

**I tried the similar issue in my environment and face same issue.**

[image]

**Tried to resolve this but there may be limitation if the value is present after 6 positions in decimal It will take it by converting into scientific notification only.**

- We can't convert it into decimal while directly in parsing that time we have to take it as `double`.
- After this we have to take a derived column and convert the value to decimal using  `toDecimal(jsondemo.Amount,20, 20)`.

[image]

**Output:-**

> Note it is only convert vale to decimal till E-6 After this it will take values with scientific notation only.

[image]